# c# reactive extensions from IEnumerable<IObservable<string>> to IObservable<string>

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I would like to use reactive extensions to write an extension method

```
public static IObservable<string> ToString(
  this IEnumerable<IObservable<string>> collection,
  string start,
  string separator,
  string stop)
  {

  }
```

which produces a stream of strings reflecting the most up to date content of the collection of streams passed as argument. I additionally provide a start string, a separator and a stop string for formatting purposes.

When all observables have fired at least once, I want to keep track of the string representation as the different observables fire updates.

For example, assuming that start is "{", separator is ";", and stop is "}", that there are 3 observables in the collection which have all first fired "0", I want "{0;0;0}" to be the initial string that is produced by the resulting observable.

Assuming now that the first observable of the collection pushes "1", I want the next string to be produced to be "{1;0;0}" and so on.

Thanks for your answers already.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe here is very similar to `CombineLatest`. Try the following:

```
public static IObservable<string> ToString(this IEnumerable<IObservable<string>> observables, string start, string separator, string stop)
{
    return observables.CombineLatest()
                      .Select(values =>
                      {
                          var sb = new StringBuilder(start);
                          var first = true;

                          foreach (var value in values)
                          {
                              if (first)
                                  first = false;
                              else
                                  sb.Append(separator);

                              sb.Append(value);
                          }

                          sb.Append(stop);
                          return sb.ToString();
                      });
}
```

Comment: I think you could change the select to use String.Join to make it even simpler.   Select(values => start + String.Join(separator, values) + stop)

Comment: That's right, but I chose to limit string concatenations.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I had thought about CombineLatest but it seems that there is no overload for enumerables. Only two streams can be combined.

Comment: @GillesMeyer I definitely have such an overload. Are you sure your Rx lib is up to date?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You're right! Now I have the overload and the solution works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you saved my day!